# Assigning a variable to jScrollPane scrollByX in horizontal image scroller?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollPane to build a horizontal image scroller with images of varying widths at http://tmcdomains.com/jScrollPane/tmc_scroll_to_animate.html.

I'd like to have the scrollpane move forward and backward by the width of each image with each click of the arrows. Ideally I'd love the scrollbar drag to do this as well, but my jQuery knowledge is shaky at best, so I'd just be happy with the click functionality. I've only gotten this far thanks to stackoverflow and the developer's documentation.

I feel like the solution is staring at me, but I can't quite make it happen.

Because I want the scroller to be flexible, and I won't always know the exact dimensions of my client's images as they update the scroller, I'm using an .each loop to cycle through the images in the .image-wrapper div, pull the width from each image, and assign the total width value to var imagesWidth to set the width on .image-wrapper:

```
// set the width of .image-wrapper based on the total width of the images in the div
// webkit browsers need width declared explicitly in image tag
var imagesWidth = 0;
var imageScrollX = 0;
$('.image-wrapper > img').each(function(index, image) {
    var $image = $(image);
    imagesWidth += $image.outerWidth() + parseInt($image.css('margin-left'), 10) + parseInt($image.css('margin-right'), 10);
    imageScrollX = $image.outerWidth();
});             
$('.image-wrapper').width(imagesWidth);
```

That's working wonderfully. I'm trying to use the same loop to assign the width of each image to var imageScrollX, and use that variable to define the X value of scrollByX on each click:

```
var api = pane.data('jsp');                     
$('#left-arrow').bind(
    'click',
    function()
    {
        api.scrollByX(-imageScrollX);                       
        return false;
    }
);
$('#right-arrow').bind(
    'click',
    function()
    {
        api.scrollByX(imageScrollX);
        return false;
    }
);
```

It's *kind of* working, but what's happening is the scrollByX value is assigning the width of the last image in the sequence for every click. Any idea how I can get the click to pull the unique width of each image in the sequence, versus just the last image in the sequence?

The working file with visible code is at http://tmcdomains.com/jScrollPane/tmc_scroll_to_animate.html